# Boost Mutex try_lock Assertion failed

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, mutex, ubuntu-14.04

I want to use a Boost Mutex to protect a software component.
In one method I use a `boost::lock_guard` and it works great.

In another method I can't use the `lock_guard` because I need the non-blocking behavior.

Here's a small example of how I use the Mutex:

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

boost::mutex mutex_lock;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    bool ret = mutex_lock.try_lock();
    if(ret != true)
        std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        std::cout << "yeah" << std::endl;
        mutex_lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

On Ubuntu 14.04 with Boost 1.54 I compile with `g++ mutex_test.cpp -lboost_system -lpthread`

This program outputs this:

```
yeah
a.out: /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:108: boost::mutex::~mutex(): Assertion `!posix::pthread_mutex_destroy(&m)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I also wrote a small C program that does the same thing directly with `pthread_mutex_trylock` and this works just fine.

In gdb I noticed that the `__nusers` variable of the mutex is zero before the `mutex_lock.unlock()` call. After the call this value is `4294967295`.

The complete output in gdb is:

```
(gdb) n
yeah
13          mutex_lock.unlock();
(gdb) p mutex_lock
$2 = {m = {__data = {__lock = 1, __count = 0, __owner = 0, __nusers = 0, __kind = 0, __spins = 0, __elision = 3, __list = {__prev = 0x0, __next = 0x0}}, __size = "\001", '\000' <repeats 21 times>, "\003", '\000' <repeats 16 times>, 
    __align = 1}}
(gdb) n
15  }
(gdb) p mutex_lock
$3 = {m = {__data = {__lock = 0, __count = 0, __owner = 0, __nusers = 4294967295, __kind = 0, __spins = 0, __elision = 3, __list = {__prev = 0x0, __next = 0x0}}, 
    __size = '\000' <repeats 12 times>, "\377\377\377\377\000\000\000\000\000\000\003", '\000' <repeats 16 times>, __align = 0}}
```

Other similar questions got the answer that they are unlocking an already unlocked mutex but in this example program this is not the case.

I also tried using `boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_lock, boost::try_to_lock);` without unlocking it manually but this results in the same assertion failure.

Am I using the Mutex wrong?

**Edit:** This code works on three other machines I tested it on. On my machine I now did:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libc6 libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0
```

but the error still occurs.

What could I do to fix this behavior of my machine?

Comment: Are you _sure_ this is also happening for the exact example? This can only mean UB. Think ODR violations, missing threads library

Comment: [does not reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd7928202b97d1d4) on coliru

Comment: You are right. I tried it on three other machines and on all of them the program works as intended. I'll edit my question. Would [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) now be a better place to ask my question?

Comment: I also asked this question on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/582311/boost-mutex-try-lock-assertion-failed-on-my-machine).